# Add an offer to an already existing user subscription in my Android app (Google Play IAP)

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

Google Play IAP allows the developer to set up offers in the app subscription with trials and discounts.

If the offer is a `developer determined` offer the developer can add logic to the backend or frontend to allow a user to subscribe with that offer depending on some condition.

This works great, but how about applying an offer to an already existing subscription?

Imagine the following scenario:

I have a referral system in my app, if the user invites someone to the app and that person subscribes to a plan, both users will receive a 20% discount.

To do that for the new user is easy, I just add that offer during that user subscription.

But for the old user, I'm not sure how to do that, since that user already has a subscription going, I can't find any API [here](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions) that would allow me to apply this offer to his existing subscription.

Is that possible somehow? Or is there some workaround to make a referral system like this work with Google Play IAP subscriptions?